# Ways to run compiled .exe from .Net Framework in Linux

Tags: c#, linux

I am creating cross-platform application in C# using VS2013 and Xamarin studio. I know that questions was asked before, but lately CoreCLR was announced as open source and available on Linux. What I've heard this is not for WinForms or WPF right?

So my question is: What are ways to run .exe application in Linux/Mac OS. I mean legal ways. Is Wine legal without buying Windows? My application is .net Framework 4.0+.
Or maybe i can open my solution in mono develop and compile it in Linux?

EDIT:
Another idea show up in my head. Maybe there is way to change my code (fe: change UI) and then Linux users will be available to open this without any additional software?
And also as i asked before, is Wine legal to run my own application?

Edit2:

So tried to do this on my own, and there is no problem to run winForms application in ubuntu. After install mono and MonoDevelop IDE i was able to run winforms.exe application. This solution gives me another question:

Is there way to run it without installing IDE?

Comment: I have done google search. As I said in my post I know about Wine, mono etc. I am asking this question, because from many ways, maybe someone with more experience can show me best way.

Comment: there is no such thing as `best way` this becomes and or boils down to preference, style and taste..

Comment: mono MyExeName.exe is the way you run it. You shouldn't need to recompile most of your code, even the Windows Forms namespace works although it remaps to GTK I think. Easiest thing to do is to just try and run it. Just WPF doesn't have a translation and for ASP sites you need to install apache with mod_mono.

Comment: MethodMan: I believe, there are things as better ways.
@RonBeyer Thanks! This should help me. Please check my post, I have add some Edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is this:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
sudo apt-get install libmono-SYSTEM*
sudo apt-get update
mono application.exe
```

This will run my application. Probably if someone else got other things than winforms, other packages could be needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that questions was asked before, but lately CoreCLR was
>   announced as open source and available on Linux. What I've heard this
>   is not for WinForms or WPF right

You're right, there's no support for Winforms and WPF in .Net Core CLR. Right now only Asp.net 5(MVC/WebAPI/SignalR) and Native applications support is available.

> What are ways to run .exe application in Linux/Mac OS.

I'm not sure what do you mean by that. There are compilers for Linux and Mac OS to run your .Net application on these platforms. As I said above there's no support for win/wpf but there's an [Asp.net console application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-asp-net-features-in-visual-studio-2015-preview-and-vs2013-update-4.aspx#_ASP.NET_5_Preview_1) supported in .Net Core that you can try at home.